# Shopify App URL forwarding error

Tags: shopify

We created the user-photos app published in the Shopify app store.

But it suddenly stopped working on all our clients stores, we have not made any changes.

The issue we see relates to the URL forwarding from Shopify. For exmaple this URL

http://www.jurawatches.co.uk/apps/userphotos/photo/index/jurawatches.myshopify.com/82247292

Should go to this URL: http://userphotos.78e.co.uk/photo/index/jurawatches.myshopify.com/82247292

But we are getting this error: We're experiencing a technical problem and we are doing everything we can to resolve it as soon as possible.

Comment: Matt, are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: Hi Edward, this is now working, thank you for fixing!